# Disable header/footer printing from Chrome

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, printing

The Chrome browser doesn't have any settings for changing or disabling header and footer data that gets printed when you go File > Print.

Apparently this is being developed but until it is does anyone know how to disable this in Windows XP.

Chrome on the Mac and Ubuntu doesn't do it so I assume it is down to a system setting that by default doesn't print header/footer information unless software over-rides this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've read it can't be done.

Comment: Sounds like a job for an extension, then.

Comment: It can be done in later versions.

Answer (score 2):

To print a page from Chrome without the headers and footers:

1. Press the key combination `Ctrl-P` for Windows or `Cmd-P` for Mac, which brings up the printing dialogue along with the Print Preview
2. Click on "More Settings"
3. Uncheck the box next to "Headers and Footers"
4. Click `Print`.

(updated 2022-06-14)

Answer (score 0):

In the print dialog, click `More settings`:

[image]

Scroll down to bottom and uncheck `Headers and footers`:

[image]